# Can we plot a particular column of a row against another column of same row in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using python to plot my data set. I want a particular column of a row to be plotted against another column of same row. To be precise, I want my two columns to be the x-axis and y-axis and then plot a particular value entered by the user to be plotted on that graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np

filename = 'friuts.csv'
raw_data = open(filename, 'rb')
data = pandas.read_csv(raw_data)
mydata = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['col1','col2'])
mydata.hist()
plt.show()
```

my data set has column with fruit name and their weights in two different columns. Can those two weights be taken as x and y axis. But, I only want a graph of single row at a time.
What I have tried is taking the entire columns of all the rows.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you want?  IE do you want a line chart?  A scatter plot?  
What's a single row "graph"?

Comment: Can you try and reformulate what you are wanting to happen? Are you trying to plot one column against another?

Comment: the thing is lets say you have a fruit call it apple but different apples will have different weights according to the quality . so i want the weight to on x-axis and some other value in y-axis  and then i take a user input of any weight . So i want the user input value to be plotted in a scatter plot to visualize weither that weight lie in the range of weights or not. Similarly i have different fruits in the database and the user will enter fruit name and its weight and according to that my program will take that particular row and plot a scatter plot @mcpeterson

Comment: @Mitch please see now, i have stated my issue

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

```
plt.scatter(mydata.col1, mydata.col2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It will take the entire column. What if i want only a single value. Lets say you have min. and max. value  and you generate random values in between them and then plot to show the user weather their value lie in range or not. I know this can be done with simple if statement but i want to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to plot a single point with the information in a given row:

1. Select the row using the fruit name, this will return a pd.Series
2. Invoke the method plot over the result

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the data frame
mydata = pd.DataFrame({
'name': ['banana', 'mango', 'lima', 'apple'],
'weight': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

# Select the fruit you want to plot. This will return a pd.Series
# including the colums 'name' and 'weight'
to_plot = mydata[mydata['name'] == 'banana']

# Call the plot function indicating the which column X and Y axis.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
to_plot.plot(x='name', y='weight', marker='o', ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Weight')
```